# Change backgroundcolor of button in flatlist onpress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I have some buttons in my flatlist like below

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item name={item.name} slug={item.slug} />;

  const Item = ({ name, slug }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        delayPressIn={0}
        onPress={() => {
          dispatch(setLanguage(slug));
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={[
            styles.item,
            { backgroundColor: languages == slug ? "#940062" : "black" },
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.title}>{name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        horizontal={true}
        data={jsonLang}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

The above code works fine, when I click it is changing the background? But background color change is delayed by 1 second. Is this the right approach to change the background color of the button?

P.S: the `setlanguage` is my reducer in my Redux

```
 setLanguage: (state, action) => {
      state.language = action.payload;
    },
```

Comment: What are `setLanguage` and `languages`? Where does it define?

Comment: setlanguage is my reducer in my redux , I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works pretty fast, here's an [example](https://snack.expo.io/@daniil.loban/flatlist-simple) I created.

Perhaps the delay is in the reducer. So I artificially slowed it down.

```
const setLanguage = (languages) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      dispatch({
        type: "setLanguage",
        value: languages
      });
    }, 1000) // <--------------------- delay
  };
}
```

but now we need to make the style apply faster. I added another field to `next_languages` ​​state:

```
const initialState = {
   languages: "1",
   next_languages: "1"
}
```

and modified the code like this:

```
const setLanguage = (languages) => {
  return (dispatch) => {

    dispatch({ // <-------------- for apply style quiqly
      type: "setNextLanguage",
      value: languages
    });

    setTimeout(()=>{
      dispatch({
        type: "setLanguage",
        value: languages
      });
    }, 1000)
  };
}
```

also added the costant to the component:

```
const fastLang = languages === next_languages 
                   ? languages 
                   : next_languages;
```

Finally, the styles are set like that and still quickly

```
{ backgroundColor: fastLang == slug ? "#940062" : "yellow" }
```

I think you can even get by with one variable (perhaps this contradicts the logic of work), but this is already refactoring.

I hope I could help.

Answer (score 2):

##### the 1-second delay not depending on `background color changing time`, but it depends on what `setLanguage` do?

if `setLanguage` change the app Language this means the all component that uses this Selector will ***re-render***

you can split background color in separator state, this will change background fast, but change language it still takes 1-second

solution with react state just for explanation (you can use Redux)

```js
//add this line
const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = react.useState(languages);


const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item name={item.name} slug={item.slug} />;

  const Item = ({ name, slug }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        delayPressIn={0}
        onPress={() => {
          setSelectedLanguage(slug); //add this line, will update color immediately
          dispatch(setLanguage(slug));
        }}
      >
        <View
          style={[
            styles.item,
            //use selectedLanguage here
            { backgroundColor: selectedLanguage === slug ? "#940062" : "black" },
          ]}
        >
          <Text style={styles.title}>{name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

};
```